# How to Select Max Numeric from Varchar Field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select userid from user;

+--------+
| userid |
+--------+
| .1.    |
| .1.1.  |
| .2.    |
| .3.    |
| .3.1.  |
| .3.1.1 |
+--------+
```

Here I want to select the maximum number (which is 3) from the first number.

```
select max(userid) as userid from user where userid like ".%.";

+--------+
| userid |
+--------+
| .3.1.  |
+--------+
```

But, that's not what I want. The output I want is 3 without the dot at both side of the number.
I want the fourth value of the

```
select userid from user;
```

Comment: the strings `.3.` and `.3.1.1` has also the maximum digit(`3`). How dou you want to distinguish ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract the first number from each `userid` string, and then take the `MAX` of those:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(userid, '.', 2), '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS userid
FROM user
```

Note that you need to `CAST` the value to an integer to ensure that e.g. `11` sorts higher than `3`.

Output

```
3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02dbc8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     user
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(userid,'.',2),'.',-1) DESC, LENGTH(userid) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select trim('.' from max(salary))   from TEST_EMPLOYEE  where salary like '._.' ; 
-- O/P 
-- 3
```